# What is the difference between "attendre quelque chose" and "s'attendre à quelque chose"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, traduction, usage

This is a question that came up in my translation class but my tutor was a little contradictory. He said that "s'attendre à quelque chose" is used where there is a connotation of anticipation, and that "attendre quelque chose" is used to express "to expect." However, the examples he gave us didn't really fit that pattern, and we didn't discuss the nuances of "s'attendre à ce que" either.

Can someone please explain the differences in usage of these? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ***S'attendre à quelque chose***:  you are **NOT sure** of what you are waiting (expect, hope ...).
2. ***Attendre quelque chose***: you are **sure** of what you are waiting for (it will happen, it is just a matter of time)

Comment: The example we had been given that fits this perfectly is  _The village clock had just struck midnight when she received the phone call she had expected for so long_ and we were told to use **attendre qc**. It makes sense now! Cheers.

Comment: Does 1. hold with «à ce que» as well?

Comment: with *à ce que* you are bound to the context; I mean it can be the case of 1 or 2. @BenKnoble

Comment: Ah merci beaucoup. Je le comprends.

Answer (score 8):

This is a case where there should be no problem, the two verbs have a clear different meaning and have a straightforward translation in English.

*attendre quelque chose* is **to wait for something**, *s'attendre à quelque chose* is **to expect something**